# How to store PagingState in Cassandra Python driver?

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, pagination, python-bytearray

I'm implementing a REST API which behind the scenes queries Cassandra (via Python driver) and returns the result. Now the items to be queried will be huge so I want to have pagination capability.

The `ResultSet` returned by execute() method has a property called `paging_state` which seems to be byte literal. I would like to return this in the response body with something like `startKey=<PAGING_STATE_VALUE>`. Currently, I see the paging state looking something like `b'\x0cFY5D70822742\x00\xf0\x7f\xff\xff\xe6\x00'`.

How should I decode it so that I can append it as a proper string in my API response body. I tried decoding with `UTF-8`, `ASCII` but they are failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paging state by definition is binary, and won't be represented as a string.

Just encode it as base64, quoted printable, uuencode, or hex string - for example by using built-in [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) module.  There are plenty of functions there, like, [hexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to convert from bytes to hex string.

Comment: Wow. That helped. I used `binascii.hexlify(paging_state).decode()` to give a hex string in response and when the API request has some value for `startKey`, I convert it to binary data by `binascii.unhexlify(startKey)`